# Rspec Throws ArgumentError with or without arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I'm trying to write a fairly straightforward test on a service object that handles an error. Rails version 5.2 and Rspec 3.8.

`app/services/application_service.rb`

```rb
class ApplicationService
  def self.call(*args, &block)
    new(*args, &block).call
  end
end
```

`app/services/basic_objects/create_payment.rb`

```rb
  module BasicObjects
    class CreatePayment < ApplicationService
      def initialize(args)
        @transaction_id = args[:transaction_id]
      end

      def call
        transaction = Transaction.find(@transaction_id)
        payment = Payment.new(transaction: transaction)
        payment.save
      rescue CustomError => e
        if /waiting/i === e.message
          puts "Ignoring exception \"#{e.message}\" to prevent retry"
        else
          raise e
        end
      end
    end
```

Here is the test

```rb
describe BasicObjects::CreatePayment, type: :model do
  describe '#call' do
    let(:params) { { transaction_id: "xyz" } }

    context 'when there is a rescued error' do
      before do
        allow_any_instance_of(Payment)
          .to receive(:save)
          .and_raise(CustomError, "waiting")
      end

      it 'does not raise an error' do
         expect { described_class.call(params) }.not_to raise_error
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And it responds with this error:
`expected no Exception, got #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

But if I remove the params and instead `expect(described_class.call).not_to raise_error`
I get an error from not sending the argument

```rb
<BasicObjects::CreatePayment (class)> received :call with unexpected arguments
         expected: ({:transaction_id=>"xyz"})
              got: (no args)
```

So, then I remove `with(params)` from the allow statement

```rb
context 'when there is a rescued error' do
    before do
      allow(described_class).to receive(:call).and_raise(CustomError, "waiting")
    end

    it 'does not raise an error' do
       expect(described_class.call).not_to raise_error
    end
  end
```

And I get

```
ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**
I have adjusted the call above to raise the error on a line in the class, rather than just in calling the class itself. However, I am still getting the same error: `expected no Exception, got #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)>`

Comment: You're subbing the class method `call`, not the instance's?

Comment: I am calling it like it's called in the application - how else what I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this was a confusing ride. Alright, so let's recap:

When you write `allow(described_class).to receive(:call).and_raise(...)`, you're saying that *this* method:

```
class ApplicationService
  def self.call(*args, &block)
    new(*args, &block).call
  end
end
```

should raise the error. When trying your code out locally, that's what actually happens.

Since the *class* `call` isn't what's being tested, I would suggest you to test it like so, instead:

```
it 'does not raise an error' do
  dbl = class_double(Transaction)
  allow(dbl).to receive(:find).and_raise(CustomError, 'waiting')
  expect { described_class.new(params).call }.not_to raise_error
end
```

You can't actually stub the instance method's `call`, because by doing so you'll also remove the actual `rescue` that you're testing.

Comment: Thank you - I added the `ApplicationService` to the post above, which does implement a class method `call` - I hope that clarifies

Comment: Sorry, that's just how it pasted into the post. It's actually all on one line.

Comment: Alright, updated my answer for the final time. This was hella confusing, lol.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and the `<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)>` was very misleading and confusing.

Given your example, the problem is likely that your `CustomError` class's `initialize` method takes 0 argument and you are passing the `"waiting"` string as part of your mock, ie. `allow_any_instance_of(Payment).to receive(:save).and_raise(CustomError, "waiting")`.

The error message is actually complaining that you are passing the wrong number of arguments in your exception as your mocked exception is raised. So this should be fixed by removing `"waiting"`:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Payment)
  .to receive(:save)
  .and_raise(CustomError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a few things at play here, so let's go one by one.

---

### Class/instance methods.

Your `create_payment.rb` defines an instance method `call` on instances of `CreatePayment`. Your test code, on the other hand, mocks and calls `call` of `described_class` — so, a class method.

You probably want to create an instance of `CreatePayment` in your specs first.

```
CreatePayment.new(args).call
```

---

### Ancestors

As defined `CreatePayment` does not have a class method `call`. But from the behaviour it seems it actually does.

When you mock a method that does not exist you get a following error message:

```
 Failure/Error: allow(described_class).to receive(:call).with(params).and_raise(CustomError, "waiting")
   SomeClass does not implement: call
```

That is **not** what happening, so check the ancestors: I managed to reproduce the error by adding a class method `call` which accepts no args to the ancestor:

```
class SomeAncestor < Object
  def self.call
    raise "Abstract!"
  end
end

class SomeClass < SomeAncestor;
end
```

This leads to the same error as you see:

```
     Failure/Error: allow(described_class).to receive(:call).with(params).and_raise(CustomError, "waiting")
       Wrong number of arguments. Expected 0, got 1.
```

Your `ApplicationService` probably has some abstract implementation of `call` class method.

The takeaway here is "Mocks should conform to the signatures of the original methods". But the root cause still seems to be the confusion between class and instance methods, so the first part still stands — `CreatePayment` needs to be instantiated first, then called.

---

### Described_class

*I'm leaving it here but it's not what's going on — edits made it clear.*

```
RSpec.describe Whatever do
  it 'does something' do
    ... described_class ...
  end
end
```

> If the first argument to an example group is a class, the class is
> exposed to each example in that example group via the
> described_class() method.

`described_class` is `Whatever` in my example above. In your spec it's `nil` as you aren't passing a class (and you probably don't expect that). It means you are trying to mock and call methods of `nil`.

And it **really** messes stuff up. I can't quite pinpoint the reason but this behaviour doesn't occur with normal objects. It actually is a common mistake, which is why you may see a warning from RSpec:

> ```
>  WARNING: An expectation of `:call` was set on `nil`. To allow expectations on `nil` and suppress this message, set `RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil` to `true`. To disallow expectations on `nil`, set `RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil` to `false`. Called from .../spec/whatever.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'`.
> ```

So specify `CreatePayment` in the call to `describe` and it should work.

Comment: Actually, I didn't include the whole test - I have updated the post above, so you can see the described class is there

Comment: Oh, cool, disregard the last part then. I've updated the answer, hope that helps

Comment: I actually think I am further confusing things because `ApplicationService` implements a class method `call` - I will update above